# Python Pandas: setting the ylim value as the maximum value in my pivot table

Tags: python, pandas

I have four pivot tables and I would like to do a chart to show them.

So far, I could get the plot doing the following but the only thing that I don't know how can achieve is to set the maximum value of the ylim pair custom for each table. Any ideas?

```
fig, axs = plt.subplots(2,2)
tablepart1.plot(title='part1', kind='bar',figsize=(20,10), ylim=(0.9,.93), ax=axs[0][0])
tablepart2.plot(title='part2', kind='bar',figsize=(20,10), ylim=(0.9,.93), ax=axs[0][1])
tablepart3.plot(title='part3', kind='bar',figsize=(20,10), ylim=(0.9,.93), ax=axs[1][0])
tablepart4.plot(title='part4', kind='bar',figsize=(20,10), ylim=(0.9,.93), ax=axs[1][1])
```

Each pivot table looks like this:

```
            METHOD  methA       methB
PART     P      J       
4        50     3   0.910996    0.909996
                5   0.913883    0.912048
                7   0.911054    0.912132
```

So, in this case, I would like to have ylim=(0.9,**.913883**) instead of ylim=(0.9,**.93**)

Comment: Try replacing that ylim by `(0.9, tablepart1['methA'].max())`

Comment: I got the desired result doing: (0.9, tablepart4.loc[:, ['methA', 'methB']].max().max()) ) Thanks, @Dark

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got the desired result doing:

```
(0.9, tablepart4.loc[:, ['methA', 'methB']].max().max()) )
```